# Using FORM DATA with Alamofire

Tags: swift2, alamofire, form-data

I am using alamofire for some time now, but I have never used a form data Post. Now I am stuck. I have 2 params **(email, password)** and don't know how POST them to server. Can anyone give me an example please?

Comment: What does the server expect? A JSON POST? A URL encoded POST? A multipart form data POST? All of these matter and all are detailed in the Alamofire [README](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire).

Comment: Hi there Cnoon :-) love your framework very much... well a form data post... i read the README but i can't figure out the solution for 2 strings with no URL path

Answer (score 13, accepted):

So my solution is.... you have to specify the **Parameter Encoding** in Alamofire. So the code will look like this.

Swift 2.0

```
func registerNewUserFormData(completionHandler: (Bool, String?) -> ()){

        // build parameters
        let parameters = ["email": "test@test.cz", "password": "123456"]

        // build request
        Alamofire.request(.POST, urlDomain + "register", parameters: parameters, encoding: .URL).responseJSON { response in

            switch response.result {
            case .Success:
                print("Validation Successful")
                if let JSON = response.result.value {
                    print(JSON)
                }

            case .Failure(let error):
                print(error)

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: "Alamofire." is now "AF."

Answer (score 22):

And here is a sample code for Alamofire 4.0 in Swift 3.0

```
    let url = "http://testurl.com"

    let parameters = [
        "email": "asd@fgh.hjk",
        "password": "55555"
    ]


    Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: URLEncoding.default).responseJSON { response in
        switch response.result {
        case .success:
            if let value = response.result.value {
                print(value)
            }
        case .failure(let error):
            print(error)
        }
    }
```

Comment: `URLEncoding.httpBody` will give more meaning.

Comment: You need to change the content also **x-www-form-urlencoded** in case its required.[Find More](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Usage.md#parameter-encoding)

Answer (score 6):

**Swift 5**

```
let url = "http://testurl.com"

let parameters = [
    "email": "asd@fgh.hjk",
    "password": "55555"
]


AF.request(url, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: URLEncoding.default).responseJSON { response in
    switch response.result {
    case .success:
        if let value = response.result.value {
            print(value)
        }
    case .failure(let error):
        print(error)
    }
}
```

Comment: 'value' is inaccessible due to 'internal' protection level

Comment: it is response.value not response.result.value by the way, but otherwise looks good