# How to make alamofire post request with "form-data" parameters

Tags: swift, alamofire, multipartform-data

How to make post request in swift using alamofire with parameters as below(screenshot from postman)image is file-type, title is text-type
[image: screen shot from postman]

I'm trying sth like this:

```
let headers = [
        "Content-Type": "application/form-data",
        "X-App-Token": user.token!
    ]
    Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData:{ multipartFormData in
        multipartFormData.append(UIImagePNGRepresentation(imgToSend)!, withName: "image")
        multipartFormData.append(titleToSend.data(using: .utf8)!, withName: "title")},
                     usingThreshold:UInt64.init(),
                     to: url!,
                     method:.post,
                     headers:headers,
                     encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
                        switch encodingResult {
                        case .success(let upload, _, _):
                            upload.responseJSON { response in
                                debugPrint(response)
                            }
                        case .failure(let encodingError):
                            print(encodingError)
                        }
    })
```

but I got error:
**[BoringSSL] Function boringssl_session_errorlog: line 2868 [boringssl_session_write] SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL(5): operation failed externally to the library**

and (this is weird) debugger goes into .success but when I log response there is error from api

Comment: Does this help ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33869058/using-form-data-with-alamofire

Comment: Try changing `multipartFormData.append(UIImagePNGRepresentation(imgToSend)!, withName: "image")` to `multipartFormData.append(UIImagePNGRepresentation(imgToSend)!, withName: "image", fileName: "sample.png", mimeType: "image/png")`

Comment: @GoodSp33d No, I know how to make normal requests, but this is specific one

Comment: @Mukesh finally! Thanks a lot! :-)

Comment: Sure, Adding this as answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing

`multipartFormData.append(UIImagePNGRepresentation(imgToSend)‌​!, withName: "image")`

to

`multipartFormData.append(UIImagePNGRepresentation(imgToSend)‌​!, withName: "image", fileName: "sample.png", mimeType: "image/png")`

If you're getting warning like:

> line 2878 [boringssl_session_write] SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL(5): operation
>   failed externally to the library

You can simply ignore it. This simply means that an operation on the TLS connection failed because the TLS was closed via the `close_notify` alert.  This sort of thing is not a problem in and of itself.

> You can disable OS logging in Xcode to make them go away. With your project window open, go to Project -> Scheme -> Edit Scheme... and add "OS_ACTIVITY_MODE" to the Environment Variables section and set its value to "disable". When you rerun the app those warnings should now not appear.

Comment: I'm trying to upload files using the fileName and mimeType parameters, but the error still happens: `line 2878 [boringssl_session_write] SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL(5): operation failed externally to the library`

Comment: has anyone gotten passed this yet?  I'm still experiencing this error even with this code.

Comment: @Mukesh did the same but still getting 
2018-09-20 11:31:13.863005+0545 SDoky[325:23893] [BoringSSL] Function boringssl_session_errorlog: line 2878 [boringssl_session_write] SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL(5): operation failed externally to the library