# Alamofire form-data” parameters type post request

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, urlsession, alamofire-request

I am trying to make a request with form-data as in Postman, however I always get the `"Parameters is invalid"` response from the server. I tried with postman it works perfectly.

`parameters: [String: String] = ["name": "name","email": "email"]`

#### Here is my code:

```swift
     let request = AF
                .request(url, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoder: URLEncodedFormParameterEncoder.default, interceptor: self.interceptor)
                .validate()
                .responseDecodable(of: KResult<T>.self) { response in
                    switch response.result {
                    case let .success(res):
                        print(res)
                        completion(.success(res.result))
                    case let .failure(error):
                        print(error)
                        completion(.error(error))
                        }
                }
```

#### PS

I looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48402559/how-to-make-alamofire-post-request-with-form-data-parameters) and many others in this website but didn't solve my problem

Comment: Little tip, you can use POSTMAN to generate `cURL`  and Alamofire to generate `cURL`, might be helpful meeting each halfway and check the differences.. (I explained it there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53637437/alamofire-with-d/53637821#53637821 ). Since we don't know what it should be (what's the POSTMAN settings, what's the doc settings of your web service?)

Comment: thanks for your reply
The doc settings for the backend it requires form-data with post command and header contains the token and the Content-Type keys

I have got the output of the two but it seems messy a little bit:
postman:
```curl --location --request POST 'http://example.com/api/v1/customer/profile/edit/' \
--header 'token: xxxxxxxx' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--form 'name=test' \
--form 'email=test@test.com' \
--form 'genders=1'```

Comment: here is the `request` curl:
```curl -v \
 -X POST \
 -H "User-Agent: Demo/1.0 (com.demo.ios; build:1; iOS 13.6.0) Alamofire/5.2.2" \
 -H "Accept-Language: en;q=1.0" \
 -H "Accept-Encoding: br;q=1.0, gzip;q=0.9, deflate;q=0.8" \
 -H "token: xxxx" \
 -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
 -d "email=dsfdsfds@tes.com&gender=1&name=testdddd" \
 "http://example.com/api/v1/customer/profile/edit/" ```

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to set the `Content-Type` key from `application/json` to

`application/x-www-form-urlencoded`